# Назначение целевого фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

У меня есть адаптер для ExpandableList, он делает listView на фрагменте TaskList, и в адаптере, при нажатии на дочерний элемент - открывается новый фрагмент TaskDialog.

Мне нужно назначить TaskList целевым для TaskDialog!

Если это делать в классе фрагмента то нет никаких проблем, а когда делаю в классе адаптера - возникает ошибка!

```
TaskDialog taskDialog = TaskDialog.newInstance(name);
        taskDialog.setTargetFragment(TaskList.class, REQUEST_ADD_TASK_CODE);
        taskDialog.show(context.getSupportFragmentManager(), TASK_DIALOG_FLAG);
```

**Вопрос:**
Можно ли так делать в классе, который не является фрагментом ?

**Возникает такая ошибка**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какая ошибка возникает?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, отредактировал вопрос!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб,  не знаю почему так происходит !

Comment: посмотрите от чего TaskFragment у вас наследуется. Если от android.app.Fragment, тогда нужно просто getFragmentManager вызывать. Или наследоваться от support Fragment'а

Comment: @AbrogPetrovich, от support Fragment'а наследуется

Comment: Вообще странно. В вопросе вы поминаете TaskDialog и TaskList только, а ошибка у вас на TaskFragment...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, немного затупил но проблему решил !!! 
setTargetFragment() принимает на вход инстанс класса Fragment, а я ему пихал класс. Конечно же так сделать нельзя, нужно было конкретный объект передавать.

Comment: @Maybe_V, опишите это в ответе)